# SOA suite 12c can not find SOA sever

Tags: soa, weblogic12c, oracle12c, osb, soa-suite

I have standalone server configured, when deploy OSB project on it, it works fine, but when I try to deploy an SOA project, it hangs at "Looking up SOA server" and then got this error message. Does anyone knows what is wrong here, thank you.

[image]

I have admin sever, soa server and osb server all up and running. Here is the proof.

[image]

Here is the update:
The connection tests are all successfully returned.
But when I try to expend this SOA folder it just keep loading...

[image]

Inside the em, it shows the servers are up and SOA infra is active. This is version 12.2 btw.

[image]

Comment: that's not a standalone domain. A standalone domain  has SOA and OSB in same server as admin. It looks like compact or expanded. Bring up the EM FMC and lets see what it says about soa infra. Does your admin server connection in JDev work? Can you connect and see soa infra?

Comment: I updated my question with 2 more screenshots. There seems to be an problem with the SOA connection... But I have no idea what is wrong.
I think this is an standalone domain, I have SOA and OSB configured in the same server with admin. But I need to start them with different command files under D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\test_domain\bin
To start the admin server I use startWeblogic.cmd in this directory. And to start the OSB and SOA, I have to run another 2 instance of startManagedWeblogic.cmd  with 2 different server names as parameter osb_server1 and soa_server1

Comment: it's not standalone. I'm sure. Unless you created it yourself, and then I'd like to know  how you did it as this version does not support standlaone at present! I would try reinstalling on a different machine and seeing from there. or log this question in the SOA forum on OTN. Is this on-premise or cloud? Also need OS and version.

Comment: I created the domain with rcu.bat file under D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\bin directory. This version does not support standalone server? Then why my OSB server works fine... This is version 12.2 not 12.1

Comment: "StandAlone" Domain is *NOT* created with RCU! It has it's own derby db and is considered a quickstart install. please refer to my notes here:https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/soa-links/soa-suite-tips-and-tricks: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#SOAQS206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a standlone domain. Instructions for standalone domain are wrong in the docs. Attached is screenshot of standalone I created.  Also successful expansion of SOA in JDeveloper. My guess is your installation is wrong.

[image]

Try installing on another machine and testing. Is this on-premise or SOA Cloud Service? IF SOA cloud service then know that deploy from JDeveloper to SOA CS is not supported in this release, per the docs.

[image]

Comment: I am confused with standalone server... After install the SOA 12c, I did create the domain myself through rcu. That is not an standalone server? This could totally be setup on another PC and I can connect it from my Jdeveloper.

Comment: NOPE. while that server "stands alone" - meaning it is  not the Integrated Domain that JDeveloper creates - it is NOT a "StandAlone" server per the doc.s Please read the docs, ok? http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#BEIHHGJB

Comment: I am not using the integrated domain... the one JDeveloper creates is using the database came with the soaqs installation file.... I have a separate Oracle database installed....

Answer (score 0):

Standalone means you create a seperate domain and server that cannot be managed or controlled by jdeveloper.. 
jdeveloper uses integrated server (integrated with jdeveloper) and uses java derby database instead of oracle database or other dbs.